passing 'Args' parameters from custom template constructor to container constructor
I'm trying to pass Args parameters from template to container deque.emplace_back() call
eg
class Collection
{
public:
    template <typename ...Args>
    Collection(const std::string& name, Args...  entries)
        : m_name(name)
    {
        m_entries.emplace_back(entries...);  // Here!!!! Entry<int>, Entry<double>, Entry<int, int> added to deque
    }

private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::deque<std::any> m_entries;
};

Collection collection1
{
    "my collection",
    Entry<int>{4},
    Entry<double>{5.5},
    Entry2<int, int>{1, 2}
};



Basically I would like to have multiple `Collection` instances, with different sets of 'Entry'-s (different types, different numbers). And want to make generic constructor for all possible combinations.

emplace_back is template with Args parametes overload
template< class... Args >
reference emplace_back( Args&&... args );

So I'd think that it might take a list of objects. But that is not compiled.
With error
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'void std::__new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::any; _Args = {Entry<int>&, Entry<double>&, Entry2<int, int>&}; _Tp = std::any]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:537:17:   required from 'static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::construct(allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::any; _Args = {Entry<int>&, Entry<double>&, Entry2<int, int>&}; _Tp = std::any; allocator_type = std::allocator<std::any>]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/deque.tcc:170:30:   required from 'std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {Entry<int>&, Entry<double>&, Entry2<int, int>&}; _Tp = std::any; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::any>; reference = std::any&]'
<source>:44:31:   required from 'Collection::Collection(const std::string&, Args ...) [with Args = {Entry<int>, Entry<double>, Entry2<int, int>}; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
<source>:58:1:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:187:11: error: no matching function for call to 'std::any::any(Entry<int>&, Entry<double>&, Entry2<int, int>&)'
  187 |         { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Full example on Godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/YoPPToEdr

I'd appreciate advise how to make this work.
Thanks

You shouldn't be using emaplce_back but just initialize in the member initializer list: Collection(const std::string& name, Args...  entries) : m_name(name), m_entries{args...} {}

hmm... does not look like that working, sorry. https://godbolt.org/z/hna4Mz71a Or I don't understand you

You need to use m_entries{entries...} not m_entries(entries...).  The other option is to use m_entries({entries...}).  The {} are necessary because you want to list initialize and that requires using {}

emplace_back is also an option, but syntax should be different: (m_entries.emplace_back(entries), ...);.

Got it, thanks @NathanOliver. If you think that worth to put as an answer, I'll tick it as a solution.

Thanks @Evg, I wanted to ask about using emplace_back, in case something similar come in future, but it would be generic function. BTW why external () are needed ?

We need [mcve].

This is a fold expression. Outer () are part of its syntax.

You don't really want to use emplace_back here.  Instead what you want to do is directly initialize the deque in the class member initializer list like you do the string member.  That'll give you:
template <typename ...Args>
Collection(const std::string& name, Args...  entries) : m_name(name), m_entries{args...} {}

Do note that we use {} in m_entries{args...} because we want to list initialize and curly braces are used for that.

If you do need to call a function then the way to do that would be
template <typename ...Args>
Collection(const std::string& name, Args...  entries)
    : m_name(name)
{
    (m_entries.emplace_back(entries), ...);
}

This is call a unary fold expression and the grammar is ( expression_using_pack op ...) or (... op expression_using_pack) depending on if you are doing a right or left fold respectively.  Here we use the comma operator to expand out the pack since the operator allows us to process the expressions in a sequenced order without doing anything else.

There isn't geometric growth at all here; emplace_back is called only once in the OP. The reason it's wrong is simply that it does not initialize an arbitrary number of elements.

@j6t Yes, for some reason I was thinking vector even though I was writing deque. post cleaned up.


m_entries.emplace_back(entries...);  // Here!!!! Entry<int>, Entry<double>, Entry<int, int> added to deque


The comment does not match the code. From the documentation for std::deque::emplace_back on cppreference.com:

Appends a new element to the end of the container.

That's a new element, singular, not plural. If you call emplace_back once, you add one new element no matter how many parameters you provide. (Multiple parameters are supported because some constructors take more than one parameter.) In contrast, the comment says three elements are to be added.
To get three new elements, you would need to call emplace_back three times. Your syntax is close, but you have only entries in your pack expansion. Your code expands to
m_entries.emplace_back(Entry<int>{4}, Entry<double>{5.5}, Entry2<int, int>{1, 2});

which tries to construct a single element from three parameters, similar to how your collection1 variable is constructed from four parameters.
If you were to include m_entries.emplace_back in the expansion, you would get multiple calls to it.
(m_entries.emplace_back(entries), ...);

expands to (with newlines added for readability)
(m_entries.emplace_back(Entry<int>{4}),
 m_entries.emplace_back(Entry<double>{5.5}),
 m_entries.emplace_back(Entry2<int, int>{1, 2}));

Three calls to emplace_back, so three elements get added to the deque. Note the outermost parentheses, as these are needed for the fold expression syntax to work.
(That being said, directly initializing the deque is preferable, since that pushes more work onto the implementation, and the implementation should know the optimal way to handle your data.)
